# Irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_3\mathbb{C}$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am working through the exercises in Fulton and Harris's Representation Theory, and am stuck on two on page 189.

Let $\text{Sym}^2V$ denote the second symmetric power of the standard 3-dimensional representation $V$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_3\mathbb{C}$ and $\Gamma_{a,b}$ be an irreducible, finite-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_3\mathbb{C}$ with highest weight $aL_1-bL_3$.

1. Show that the representation $\wedge^2(\text{Sym}^2V)$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma_{2,1}$.
2. Determine the irreducible factors of the representation $\wedge^3(\text{Sym}^2V)$.

It seems that both questions can be done by drawing the weight diagrams, but alas I do not think I have developed the intuition for what irreducible representations I should try, or how to proceed further. Would anybody have any pointers? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the two problems, $V$ denotes the standard 3-dimensional representation, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct-- I  am sorry I forgot to be more specific.

Comment: For this Lie algebra $Sym^nV$ is always irreducible of highest weight $n\lambda_1$ (in Humphreys' IMHO more standard notation, probably $nL_1$ in yours). So $Sym^2V$ is the irreducible rep of highest weight $2L_1$. To get the weights of the alternating powers, you need to sum up distinct weights. You probably also need to work a bit with the weight multiplicities. I haven't checked. Yes, can't do without weight diagrams.